# MongoDB - Why the values are not storing in documents?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm facing an issue where I'm trying to store data from a form submission in MongoDB using Mongoose, but only the id field is being stored, while the other input fields are not saved. I have checked my schema definition and form setup, but I couldn't identify the problem.

here is my code

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
//const hbs=require("hbs");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require("./db/conn");
const Index = require("./models/index_schema");
const Doctor = require("./models/doctor_schema");
const Enterdetails = require("./models/enterdetails_schema");

const port = process.env.PORT || 80;

//const static_path =path.join(__dirname,"../public");
// Set the public directory as the static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// Middleware setup
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//app.use(express.static(static_path));
//app.set("view engine","hbs");
//app.use('views', express.static(path.join(__dirname,"views")));

// get request for index.html
//for index.html
// Serve index.html
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html"));
});

/*app.get("/index",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("index");
})*/

//create a new user in database
app.post("/index", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const indexSchema = new Index({
      name: req.body.name,
      phone_number: req.body.phone_number,
      password: req.body.password,
    });

    const userphn = await Index.findOne({ phone_number: req.body.mobile_number });

    if (!userphn) {
      return res.send("User not found"); // Send an error response if the user is not found
    }

    /*if (userphn.password !== req.body.password) {
        return res.send("Incorrect password"); // Send an error response if the password is incorrect
      }*/

    await indexSchema.save();
    console.log(indexSchema);
    res.status(201).redirect("index.html"); // Send a success response if everything is fine
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error);
    console.log(error);
  }
});

// Serve enterdetails.html
// Serve enterdetails.html
app.get("/enterdetails.html", (req, res) => {
  return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public", "enterdetails.html"));
});

// Redirect to enterdetails.html
app.get("/open-enterdetails-page", (req, res) => {
  res.redirect("/enterdetails.html");
});

// const Enterdetails = mongoose.model('Enterdetails', enterdetailsSchema);

app.post("/enterdetails", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const enterdetailsData = new Enterdetails({
      name: req.body.name,
      age: req.body.age,
      blood_group: req.body.blood_group,
      phone_number: req.body.phone_number,
      date: req.body.date,
      medical_history: req.body.medical_history,
      password: req.body.password,
    });
    console.log("Body: ", req.body);
    await enterdetailsData.save();
    console.log(enterdetailsData);
    res.status(201).send("/enterdetails.html");
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error);
    console.log(error);
  }
});

// Serve doctor.html
app.get("/doctor.html", (req, res) => {
  return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public", "doctor.html"));
});

// Redirect to doctor.html
app.get("/open-doctor-page", (req, res) => {
  res.redirect("/doctor.html");
});

// post request for doctor.hbs
app.post("/doctor", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const doctorSchema = new Doctor({
      name: req.body.name,
      phone_number: req.body.phone_number,
      password: req.body.password,
    });

    await doctorSchema.save();
    console.log(doctorSchema);
    res.status(201).redirect("/doctor.html");
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error);
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`server is running at port no ${port}`);
});
```

all the values in my form would be stored in my MongoDB database successfully ... but that isn't the case ... only the object id is stored.

Comment: There may be problem in parsing request body,  can you `console.log("Body: ", req.body)`? If it is null or undefined, you need apply this: `app.use(express.json());`

Comment: its giving an output as Body: undefined and i have already added app.use(express.json()); what should i do now?

Comment: can you post the index/app.js file

Comment: i posted the index/app.js which is generating successful values

Comment: Where did you apply `app.use(express.json());`? Also can you add the schema code? And how do you send the request body?

Comment: Can you add screenshot of the request body in the browser developer tools when you submit the form?

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of replacing the code ... i just replaced the same code with the original one and it worked

her is my app.js code

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const express=require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app=express();
const mongoose=require("mongoose");
//const router=express.Router();
require("./db/conn");
const Index=require("./models/index_schema");
const Doctor=require("./models/doctor_schema");
const Enterdetails=require("./models/enterdetails_schema");


//router
//var fetchRouter = require('./models/fetch');
//app.use('/', fetchRouter);
//router.get('/fetch-data',fetchRouter.fetchData);




const port =process.env.PORT  || 80;

//const static_path =path.join(__dirname,"../public");
// Set the public directory as the static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));



app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false })); 
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// Middleware setup
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());



// get request for index.html
//for index.html
// Serve index.html
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
  });
  


//create a new user in database
app.post("/index", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const indexSchema = new Index({
        name: req.body.name,
        date: req.body.date,
        phone_number: req.body.phone_number,
        password: req.body.password
      });
  
      const userphn = await Index.findOne({ phone_number: req.body.mobile_number });
  
      if (!userphn) {
        return res.send("User not found"); // Send an error response if the user is not found
      }
  
      /*if (userphn.password !== req.body.password) {
        return res.send("Incorrect password"); // Send an error response if the password is incorrect
      }*/

  
      await indexSchema.save();
      console.log(indexSchema)
      res.status(201).redirect("index.html"); // Send a success response if everything is fine
  
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(400).send(error);
      console.log(error);
    }
  });



    // Serve enterdetails.html
    // Serve enterdetails.html
app.get('/enterdetails.html', (req, res) => {
  return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'enterdetails.html'));
});

// Redirect to enterdetails.html
app.get('/open-enterdetails-page', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/enterdetails.html');
});
  
  
  // const Enterdetails = mongoose.model('Enterdetails', enterdetailsSchema);
  
  app.post('/enterdetails', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const appointment = new Enterdetails({
        name: req.body.name,
        age: req.body.age,
        blood_group: req.body.blood_group,
        phone_number: req.body.phone_number,
        medical_history: req.body.medical_history,
        password: req.body.password,
      });
  
      await appointment.save();
      console.log(appointment);
      res.status(201).send('/index.html');
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(400).send(error);
      console.log(error);
    }
  });



// Serve doctor.html
app.get('/doctor.html', (req, res) => {
    return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'doctor.html'));
  });
  
  // Redirect to doctor.html
  app.get('/open-doctor-page', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/doctor.html');
  });



// post request for doctor.html
app.post('/doctor', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const doctorSchema = new Doctor({
      name: req.body.name,
      phone_number: req.body.phone_number,
      password: req.body.password,
    });
    const userphn = await Index.findOne({ phone_number: req.body.mobile_number });
  
      if (!userphn) {
        return res.send("User not found"); // Send an error response if the user is not found
      }

    await doctorSchema.save();
    console.log(doctorSchema);
    res.status(201).redirect('/doctor.html');
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error);
    console.log(error);
  }
});


//post request for  table.html
// app.get('/table.html', async (req, res) => {
//   try {
//     const userinfo = await Fetch.find();
//     res.render('index', { fetchSchema });
//     console.log(userinfo);
//   } catch (error) {
//     res.status(500).send(error);
//   }
// });


//fetch all

// app.get("/fetchdata",(res,req)=>{
//   userTable.find((err,val)=>{
//     if(err)
//     {
//       console.log(err);
//     }else{
//       res.render(val);
//     }
//   })
// })



app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`server is running at port no ${port}`);
})
```